# AngularJS + style is not applied to field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to apply a color to a message on an api response.

example:

angularJS:

```
 .then(function (response) {
    angular.element(document.getElementById("msg")).css('color', '#00662f');
    $scope.Messages = response.data;
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="msg" ng-repeat="msg in Messages">{{msg}}</div>
```

but this line:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("msg")).css('color', '#00662f');
```

does not seem to be applied to the color of the message.

Can you tell what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Erasmo

**UPDATE** - My Solution

added a boolean

```
$scope.IsColor == true;
```

Set it to false/true based on the API response:

```
if (response.data.indexOf("sucessfully added") !== -1) {
    $scope.Messages = response.data;
    $scope.IsColor = true;
    angular.element("#msg").focus()
    return true;
}
else {
    $scope.Messages = response.data;
    $scope.IsColor = false;
    angular.element("#msg").focus()                           
    return false;
}
```

Then in the HTML

```
<div id="msg" ng-repeat="msg in Messages" ng-class="$scope.IsColor ? 'text-green' : 'text-red'">{{msg}}</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use angular.element to achieve it. It's really a bad try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it via `ng-class` or `ng-style`. Please see stackblitz for how to update style:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-puf49l

Beside the style, in your HTML:

```
<div id="msg" ng-repeat="msg in Messages">{{msg}}</div>
```

You should replace **id** with **class**, using id's to identify elements is often considered a bit bad, because id's are global and it would instantly mess up if I happen to have a collision.

Comment: hello @huan feng, so all I need to do to see a difference, is to change id with class?

Comment: Have you seen the stackblitz example? Actually there are several issues in your code. 1. You shouldn't use id for the styling. 2. you should avoid using way like angular.element to change the color of element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("msg")).css('color', '#00662f');
```

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: It did not work. Maybe I should use a boolean scope variable and then check for its value in the html?